# QUASAR - Justify-center and screen breakpoints

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I’m having this issue, I searched in the forum but didn’t find anything related.

I am trying to use justify-center for small screens and justify-end for large screens. Reading the docs I found this:

[image]

So I tried to use it as `justify-sm-center` and `justify-lg-end` but haven’t been able to make it work. I made this fiddle to demonstrate it:

https://jsfiddle.net/leoprada/3b40vn6g/

```html
<div class="row">
    <p>Class: justify-center applied when BP lg (justify-lg-center) and justify-end on BP sm (justify-sm-end) </p>
    <div class="row col-12 justify-sm-end justify-end-sm justify-lg-center bg-black">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-6 bg-blue q-py-md text-center">
            col-4
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-green q-py-md text-center">
            Col-4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don’t really know if I am doing something wrong.

(I know how to make it work by my own using CSS but I’d rather use the predefined quasar class, of course)

Comment: Did you enable cssAddon (quasar.conf > framework > cssAddon: true) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the cssAddon / flex-addon. If you didn't install quasar via its native CLI and thus don't have a *quasar.conf*, you need to import the *flex-addon.sass* file.

*main.js/ts*

```
import ...

// Import Quasar css
import "quasar/src/css/index.sass"
import "quasar/src/css/flex-addon.sass" // <--- NEW

createApp...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think the breakpoints work on rows (only items within rows), so I think to do what you want, you would have to use the Vue Class Bindings with [breakpoints](https://quasar.dev/options/screen-plugin) or [platform detection](https://v0-14.quasar-framework.org/components/platform-detection.html). Something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div :class="$q.platform.is.mobile ? 'justify-end' : 'justify-center'"  class="row col-12 bg-black">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-6 bg-blue q-py-md text-center">
      col-4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```